# Lock down changes to Azure Dev Ops Board for certain users

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to have a user in Azure Devops that only has access to review the test plans sections in Azure Devops. I don't want the users to be able to go to the Board area and make modifications.

I've attempted to make users in the different types (Basic, Basic + test plan) but they always have access to edit items on the board. I tried creating them as a stakeholder and that didn't work either.

The last things I tried was creating a group and denying access to everything except project info and test plans, but this didn't work either.[Picture of Project setting for test plan group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGwN7.png)

Is there any other approach I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user has access level(stakeholder, basic or basic + test plan), the user will has access to view the Board.

You could refer to this doc about [Access Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops).

But you could set the permission for the users to prevent them from modifying the work item.

You could go to `Project Settings -> Project configuration -> Select the Area -> Security`.

[image]

You could deny the `Edit work items in this node` or `View work items in this node` .

[image]